# Qual è il significato di "tirar fuori di mano" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La chimera*,  di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> Ma l’inquisitore di Milano, quando infine s’era deciso a far sentire la sua voce – con un discorsetto tutto infarcito di citazioni dalle Scritture e dai Padri della Chiesa, e con quel suo eterno sorriso sulle labbra, da **tirar fuori di mano** gli schiaffi ai Santi – s’era mostrato molto tiepido, se non proprio freddo, per l’affare della “strega di Zardino”: arrivando a suggerire al povero Manini di… lasciar perdere!

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "tirar fuori di mano" in questo brano.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fuorimano/) ho trovato questa definizione:

> **fuorimano** (o **fuòri mano**; anche **fuòri di mano**) locuz. usata come avv. e agg., invar. – Lontano dall’abitato, in luogo remoto, periferico, appartato, o comunque scomodo da raggiungere: *abitare f.; una casa scomoda e f.; stradine f.; girellando una mattina, Càpito in Sant’Ambrogio di Milano, in quello vecchio, là, fuori di mano* (Giusti).

Tuttavia, non mi sembra che questo abbia molto senso nel contesto del passaggio sopra citato. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "fuori di mano" in questo testo?

Comment: No, la locuzione da cercare in questo caso è *tirar fuori [da qualcosa]*, non *fuori di mano* :)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Quindi, il significato sarebbe più o meno che il sorriso dell'Inquisitore di Milano era tale da far cavare schiaffi dalle mani dei santi?

Comment: @Charo esatto! Significa in pratica che l'atteggiamento era tale che uno si sentiva in pratica in dovere di pigliarlo a ceffoni!

Comment: Lo dico meglio: l'atteggiamento del soggetto era talmente esasperante da forzare pure un santo a prenderlo a sberle :)

Comment: Nota: in questi casi esiste anche il modo di dire _"prudere le mani"_

Comment: Beh... adesso qualcuno dovrebbe scrivere la risposta.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ti andrebbe di scrivere una risposta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come ha osservato @DenisNardin, la locuzione da cercare in questo caso è *tirar fuori [da qualcosa]*, non *fuori di mano*. Nel [dizionario Hoepli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/tirare.php), per esempio, si trova

> **Tirare fuori**, cavare, estrarre.

Cioè, il significato letterale dell'espressione sarebbe che quel "eterno sorriso sulle labbra" dell'Inquisitore di Milano era tale da far cavare schiaffi dalle mani dei santi.

La locuzione significa che l'atteggiamento del soggetto era talmente esasperante da forzare anche un santo a prenderlo a sberle.

Un modo di dire simile è *"far prudere le mani"* .

Comment: Penso sarebbe una buona idea aggiungere alla risposta il contributo di @DenisNardin: così sarebbe più ragionata.

Comment: Cerco di farlo io stessa, correggetemi poi tutto quello che considerate opportuno.

Comment: @Charo ottima revisione!